# What's the benefit of copper plating paper clips?

Tags: metallurgy

(Sorry, not an engineer or student, just looking for the most metallurgically relevant stack.)

Recently I was in someone's office and, while playing with their paper clips, it occurred to me that copper is kind of a precious material for humble paper clips ... one look at the box, they're merely copper *plated*. But why even do that though?

Why not just leave them bare steel or aluminium or whatever they are made of (which, curiously, the box doesn't say)?

[image: ip]

Comment: A benefit is that they leave green marks on the paper if they get wet over time.

Comment: @SolarMike this is what's called _green washing_, yes? ^_^

Comment: Perhaps it's just because copper has a nice colour?

Comment: Yep. Aesthetics, "classy, expensive" looks.

Comment: When your four-year-old sticks one in an outlet, the breaker will trip really fast :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes them not rust in humid conditions while holding papers together. The required amount of copper coating on the clip is extremely small.